# Can I travel for 2 years with my cat and two dogs?

Tags: cats, dogs, travel

I used to travel a lot some years ago.

I felt the urge to settle. Bought a house, and have rescued one cat and two dogs now.
I feel the urge to travel again...

I am older now, I wouldn't want to travel from hostel to hostel. I would choose a place and maybe stay 3 months or so. I am thinking of doing this for about 2 years or so.

Would it be possible to take my pets with me like this? Travel to a place, live there and move on?

The alternative so far has been that I leave my pets home, but then I have to have someone watch them and I can't handle that myself very good...I miss my loved pets, and then I don't travel more than 2 weeks or so...

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26687/should-i-bring-my-cat-with-me-if-i-travel-for-1-month also related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23388/what-to-do-when-you-have-two-large-dogs-and-travel-a-lot-for-work

Comment: Do you think about some kind of mobile home? Or do you want to move from house/hotel to house/hotel? I would assume a sort of mobile home, like a camper or similar, would be a good option to take the animals with you. (The dogs more sure than the cat)

Comment: That'd be a great option, but unfortunately, my next targeted destinations are in another continent....

Comment: If you stay for some stops on one continent, you could think about rent or buy and resell a mobile home there. Depending of the continent, but I know for example in Germany it is popular to go camping with dogs, so there are multiple options to rent camper-mobiles with integrated crate/bed for the dog and installed save place during the riding

Comment: one example in english language: https://www.4pfoten-mobile.de/ you can find much more with "dog camper" as search term

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my personal, subjective opinion:

You could travel with dogs, but it would mean a lot of stress for the cat.

Dogs are (in general) very social animals and their pack is their home. If the pack moves, each dog will want to move as well. There are many people who travel together with their dogs or don't even have a fixed place to live but move from one place to the next. Their dogs always follow them.

Cats, on the other hand, are more territorial than social. Especially male cats often care more for their territory than for their food providers. Moving around with a cat is difficult, because it means always being in unknown territories and as soon as the cat had time to live in, you move on.

Of course there are vast differences in personality, but it's very usual for cats to act scared and hide away if their owners move to a new house, even if the family members are around to provide social stability.

The only way I could imagine traveling with a cat is in a big caravan or mobile home and if the cat gets used to the frequent moves from a very young age.